# Running tests in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit4

I have this test class

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializr, using embedded Tomcat + Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used :

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

my classes:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    public class TdkApplicationTests {

        @Test
        public void contextLoads() {
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public class PersistenceConfig {

        @Bean
        public  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
        }


        @Bean 
        public IOTEcoSystemManager iOTEcoSystemManager() {
            return new IOTEcoSystemManagerImpl();
        }

        @Bean 
        public DeviceEventRepository deviceEventRepository() {
            return new JdbcDeviceEventRepository();
        }

        @Bean 
        public DeviceRepository deviceRepository() {
            return new JdbcDeviceRepository();
        }

        /**
         * Creates an in-memory "books" database populated 
         * with test data for fast testing
         */
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource(){
            return
                (new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder())
                .addScript("classpath:db/H2.schema.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:db/H2.data.sql")
                .build();
        }

    }



    @ContextConfiguration(classes={PersistenceConfig.class})
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class BookManagerTests {

        /**
         * The object being tested.
         */
        @Autowired
        BookManager bookManager;


        @Test
        public void testfindDeviceByKey() {
            Device device = bookManager.findDeviceByKey("C380F");
            assertNotNull(device);
            assertEquals("C380F", device.getDeviceKey());
            assertEquals(1, device.getId().longValue());
        }

        @Test
        public void testfindDeviceByKeyFail() {
            Device device = null;
            try {
                device = bookManager.findDeviceByKey("C380FX");
            } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException erdae) {
                assertNotNull(erdae);
            }
            assertNull(device);

        }
    }

@Service("bookManager")
public class BookManagerImpl implements BookManager {
...
}
```

If I run all the test of the package I got this error:

```
unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10092 table: T_COMPANY
```

because the script runs twice. If I remove

```
classes={PersistenceConfig.class}
```

from BookManagerTests I got this dependency problem

```
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

If I run both test individually everything is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PersistenceConfig and its content seem to be created twice: first time as ordinary bean and second time as config (that's right). I recommend to create single main test class with all annotations and then extend your tests (without any annotation) from it.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={PersistenceConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public abstract class MainTest {
}

public BookManagerTest extends MainTest {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems the constraint validation happens because PersistentConfig is loaded twice, and that masks your second problem. Where is BookManager defined? Are you sure your scanning the classpath correctly for it, if it's annotated with @repository?